# Top variables from LASSO not significant in regular regression

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, linear-model, lasso

I have a table with 65 records and 1000 variables for which I use LASSO to perform feature selection.  Then, in order to quantify the relative impact of the variables, I regress the response only on these variables using traditional linear regression.

Out of the 25 variables, only about 5 are statistically significant.  How would I interpret the fact that LASSO tells us that 25 of these variables out of 1000 are important, but linear regression then indicates that only 5 of these are significant?

Comment: You need a bit more information.  How did you tune the regularization parameter in LASSO?

Comment: You cannot treat the significance of the selected variables at face value because the significance is conditional of those variables being selected to begin with. Which actually tells that they could be even less significant unconditionally, if I am not mistaken. Also, 25 variables for 65 data points sounds like too many.

Comment: @MatthewDrury, I selected the lambda that gave the simplest model where the standard error of the cross validation error is within 1 SE of the minimum cross-validation error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kodiologist rightfully points out that there is no reason whatsoever to believe these concepts to be related.

Richard Hardy, in the comments, points out the major statistical flaw in your procedure.  To elaborate a bit, the cross validation procedure you did to select the optimal value of the regularization parameter is itself also subject to noise.  If you bootstrap your data and do the entire procedure many times, you will find that your choice of the regularization parameter is not consistent.  The rub is that your confidence intervals for your estimated parameters need to reflect this variation as well, and it is this source of variation that Richard points out is causing your intervals to be too small.

One simple way to convince yourself of this is to consider the predictors that LASSO did *not* include in the model.  In your subsequent linear regression you left them out.  You have essentially then said, with 100% certainty, that these parameters *are* zero.  The others that you left in the model you have ascribed some variation to.  Why the difference?  Do you *really* believe that the true parameters for the selected away variables are zero, with 100% confidence?

Thankfully, this thought experiment also points to a solution.  If you would like to use LASSO and also estimate the standard errors of the final parameters, you can use a bootstrap procedure.

```
for each bootstrap sample B from your training data
    split B into cross validation folds
    for each cross validation fold
        fit LASSO for each considered regularization parameter
        get estimate of out of sample error for each regularization parameter
    find optimal regularization parameter for training data B
    fit LASSO model with the optimal parameter on the entire sample B
    record the estimated parameters from the full LASSO model on B
return the variance of the estimated parameters over the bootstrap samples
```

This gives you a *fair* record of the variance in your estimated parameters.

Comment: Matthew Drury (@Matthew Drury), thanks for that detailed response.  Is it correct to say that I would then be able to divide the value of the parameters by the standard error to get a t-statistic?

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to believe that the resulting sampling distribution of the parameter would have any parametric form, so I don't think that the resulting statistic would have any meaning.  In this situation, I generally look at: 1) the probability that a parameter is non-zero in the model, 2) the conditional variance of the parameter given that it is selected.  And use these to explain the model to audiences.

Answer (score 5):

Although hasty glosses of lasso regularization and statistical significance might suggest that they do the same thing, they do very different things. The statistical significance of a coefficient tests a null hypothesis about that coefficient given a smaller model as a background assumption. Lasso regularization, on the other hand, estimates coefficient values while minimizing a penalty term based on the sum of the absolute values of the coefficients. These very different goals mean that there's no reason these methods should agree about anything.

> in order to quantify the relative impact of the variables, I regress the response only on these variables using traditional linear regression.

Why not use the coefficients from the lasso model that you already fit? Isn't that the model you're trying to assess?

Comment: Kodiologist, to answer your last question, I was under the impression that one cannot use the coefficients from the results of the Lasso to interpret the effect of a unit change in the explanatory variable on the response variable (in the way that we are able to do this for linear regression).  Perhaps we in fact can use this same approach.

Comment: @matsuo_basho That interpretation only depends on the functional form of the model.  So yes, you can still interpret them in that way, with all of the same caveats.

Comment: I have already ran a regression with only the variables with non-zero coefficients from Lasso and presented the findings. Is there a way to reconcile the coefficients from the regression compared to those from Lasso?  Specifically, the coefficients of the regression model variables tend to be larger (for example 3x larger for a particular variable) compared to the lasso.  Can I use either or is using the results of the regression completely incorrect due to reasons you described above?

Comment: "the coefficients of the regression model variables tend to be larger" — Yes, shrinking coefficients is exactly what the lasso does.